# Proving monotonicity of continuous linear functional

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, research

Hi I am interested in resolving the following problem from the bottom of page 147 from [a paper](http://www.dmi.unict.it/ojs/index.php/lematematiche/article/view/863) I am revising:

Given a function $$a: \Omega \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{N}, a(x,u,\xi) = \{a_{i}(x,u,\xi)\}~~i=1,...,N$$

is a Caratheodory vector-valued function, that is, measurable with respect to $x$ in $\Omega$ for every $(s,\xi)$ in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^{N}$ and continuous with respect to $(s,\xi)$ in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^{N}$ for almost every $x$ in $\Omega$. It is also given that $a$ is monotone: $$\sum^{N}_{i=1}[a_{i}(x,s,\xi)-a_{i}(x,s,\xi^{*})](\xi_{i}-\xi_{i}^{*}) > 0$$ for a.e. $x$ in $\Omega$, for every $\xi,\xi^{*} \in \mathbb{R}^{N}$, $\xi \neq \xi^{*}$.

Consider another Caratheodory function $g: \Omega \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, such that $g \in L^{1}(\Omega)$ and it satisfies $$g(x,y)y \geq 0$$ for a.e. $x \in \Omega$ and for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$.

If we define continuous linear functionals $Au$ and $Gu$ as:
$$\langle Au, v \rangle := \int_{\Omega}a(x,u,\nabla u)\cdot \nabla v dx$$ and $$\langle Gu,v \rangle := \int_{\Omega}g(x,u)vdx$$

for $u,v \in C^{\infty}_{c}(\Omega)$. How would you show that $A + G$ is monotone, which means, $$\langle (A + G)(u_{1})-(A+G)(u_{2}),u_{1}-u_{2}\rangle \geq 0~~~\forall u_{1},u_{2} \in C^{\infty}_{c}(\Omega)$$

Let me know if something is unclear. Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Does the monotonicity of $a$ imply the monotonicity of $A$? $\langle (A+G)(u_1-u_2),u_1-u_2)\rangle =\langle A(u_1-u_2),u_1-u_2\rangle + \langle G(u_1-u_2),u_1-u_2\rangle\geq 0$

Comment: @MBYagbasan It might, but it does not follow easily due to the fact that the monotonicity of $a$ is given with respect to the third independent variable, which I have denoted $\xi$. This is one of the things I am trying to figure out in order to get monotonicity of $A+G$.

Answer (score 1):

The authors may be using some notion of monotonicity different from what you expect (they never defined it). The inequality $$\langle (A + G)(u_{1})-(A+G)(u_{2}),u_{1}-u_{2}\rangle \geq 0\quad \forall u_{1},u_{2} \in C^{\infty}_{c}(\Omega) \tag{1}$$
does not follow from their assumptions. Indeed, since both $A$ and $G$ could be scaled independently from one another (the constants in their structural assumptions are not related), we can only expect (1) to hold if it holds for $A$ and $G$ separately. But it fails for $G$: the inequality 
$$
\int_\Omega \left[g(x,u_1(x))- g(x,u_2(x))\right]\left[u_1(x)-u_2(x)\right]\ge 0
\tag{2}$$
need not hold. For example, let
$$
g(x,u) = \frac{u}{1+u^2}
$$
then the inequality (2) becomes 
$$
\int_\Omega \frac{(u_1-u_2)^2 (1-u_1u_2)}{(1+u_1^2)(1+u_2^2)}\ge 0
\tag{3}$$
Clearly, (3) is false when we have, say, $u_1=2$ and $u_2=3$ on most of the domain.

Inequality  (2) would be true if $g$ was assumed to be increasing with respect to $u$.